# Trying to get property of non-object error in Yii

Tags: php, linux, object, properties, yii

Case 1: I get an array of CActiveRecords and try to loop over it as shown below:

```
foreach ($pendingTasks as $task)
    {
        if($task->task->employee_id=="1")
        {
            //some logic here
        }
    }
```

I get "Trying to get property of non-object "

Case 2: If I try:

```
$pendingTasks = TaskLog::model()->findByPk("1");
    if($pendingTasks->task->employee_id=="1")
    {
        //some logic here   
    }
```

This works.
Why is this so? Am I doing any thing wrong here?

Comment: Dump $task from the list which you did iterate on your server, the error came because you access task from $task which has been null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the `tasks` in `$pendingTasks` must not have a relation. You can check by simply adding an `isset()` like so:

```
foreach ($pendingTasks as $task) {
    if(isset($task->task) && $task->task->employee_id=="1") {
        //some logic here
    } else {
        echo "{$task->id} doesn't have a task relation";
    }
}
```

Assuming `$pendingTasks` are instances of `TaskLog` also.