# yii : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, yii

Well, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335513/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error-in-yii), but i can't see the relation with my error.. I am newbie--well I know this excuse is unacceptable but i try to find the solution first before i ask it here. I hope you can help me.

so I have this code, i put this code in views :

```
foreach ($budget as $budget):
            if (array_key_exists('year', $_GET)) {
                $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->condition = 'year = ' . $_GET['year'];
                $criteria->addCondition('mapping_id = '. $budget->id);
                $yearBudget = YearlyBudget::model()->find($criteria);
            } else {
                $yearBudget = new YearlyBudget;
            } 
 endforeach;
```

and then after that code, i simply echo this :

```
echo $yearBudget->budget;
```

then i got non-object error. I just don't understand and stuck in this code. Please help, and thank you.

print_r($yearBudget); :

```
YearlyBudget Object(
[_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
[_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [mapping_id] => 1
        [year] => 2012
        [budget] => 2000000
        [balance] => 2000000
        [created] => 2013-11-20 10:16:29
        [updated] => 
    )

[_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
    )

[_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
[_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 1
[_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
[_errors:CModel:private] => Array
    (
    )

[_validators:CModel:private] => 
[_scenario:CModel:private] => update
[_e:CComponent:private] => 
[_m:CComponent:private] =>
```

)

Ah, sorry if my english is bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the object is empty or not  before you access it's attribute.

```
if($yearBudget){
  echo $yearBudget->budget;
}else{
  echo "No Yearly Budget with given criteria";
}
```

If you are not getting desired result, check the conditions carefully

```
$criteria->condition = 'year = ' . $_GET['year'];
$criteria->addCondition('mapping_id = '. $budget->id);
```

Comment: ah, it works, thank you... by the way, what the difference between this with model()->exist?

Comment: the find method returns null if it doesn't find any thing, if you check for existing record first, you will be sure that you have a populated model to work with

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advice using `CHtml::value()` method http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#value-detail

```
echo CHtml::value($yearBudget, 'budget');
```

this is ivery handy when it comes to multiple related object, and you do not need to check out every related model existence to access its attributes

```
echo CHtml::value($budget, 'company.fiscalYear.creator.id');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure you have a valid model after trying to find it with your criteria :

```
foreach ($budget as $budget):
            if (array_key_exists('year', $_GET)) {
                $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->condition = 'year = ' . $_GET['year'];
                $criteria->addCondition('mapping_id = '. $budget->id);

                if(YearlyBudget::model()->exists($criteria)) // check if this exists
                    $yearBudget = YearlyBudget::model()->find($criteria);
                else
                    $yearBudget = new YearlyBudget; // or throw an exception or something
            } else {
                $yearBudget = new YearlyBudget;
            } 
 endforeach;
```

Comment: i tried, and you right, it is not exist. I am not understand, i tried to print_r() the $yearBudget and it show me array.. i'll edit the post to show the result of print_r()