# Another yii - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, yii

sory another yii question, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090528/yii-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object)  bust seems doesnt works.
I have this error, still learning yii

Trying to get property of non-object
    D:\xampp\htdocs\mou\protected\views\mou\view.php(26)

Did i miss something? thanks before.

```html
D:\xampp\htdocs\mou\protected\views\mou\view.php(26)

14             'value'=>Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd/MM/yyyy',$model->tgl_perjanjian),
15         ),
16         array(
17             'name'=>'tgl_awal',
18             'value'=>Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd/MM/yyyy',$model->tgl_awal),
19         ),
20         array(
21             'name'=>'tgl_akhir',
22             'value'=>Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd/MM/yyyy',$model->tgl_akhir),
23         ),
24         array(
25             'name'=>'Mitra KY',
26             'value'=>$model->mitra_mous->mitra->nama,
27         ),
28         'lingkup_kerjasama',
29         'penandatangan',
30         'jabatan_penandatangan',
31         array(
32             'name'=>'file',
33             'type'=>'raw',
34             'value'=>CHtml::link($model->file,Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/files/mou/' .$model->file),
35         ),
36     ),
37 )); ?>
```

this is my models Mitra.php

```html
 public function relations()
 {
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
   'jenis0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'JenisMitra', 'jenis'),
   'kab0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Wilayah', 'kab'),
   'prov0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Wilayah', 'prov'),
   'mitra_mous' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MitraMou', 'mitra_id'),
  );
 }
```

and this is models Mou.php

```html
 public function relations()
 {
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
   'mitra_mous' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MitraMou', 'mou_id'),
   'mitras' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Mitra', 'mitra_id','through'=>'mitra_mous'),
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line 26 to the code below.

use this code below

`'value'=>$model->mitras->nama,`

Comment: can you do this on line 26 to check what does it return ..

`print_r($model->mitras->nama);
exit;
'value'=>$model->mitras->nama,` maybe it is not returning any value.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in 
D:\xampp\htdocs\mou\protected\views\mou\view.php on line 26

is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: can you update ur question with complete code of view.php

Comment: Here it is 

array(
   'name'=>'Mitra KY',
   print_r($model->mitras->nama); exit; 'value'=>$model->mitras->nama,
  ),

Comment: Well I prefer you to please print the `$model->mitras->nama` or `$model->mitra_mous->mitra->nama`  in your controller first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `mitra_mous` relation is the problem. Due to the fact that the relation is a one-to-many relation, $model->mitra_mous will return an array. You cannot try to get a property from an array, so `$model->mitra_mous->mitra` is invalid. Maybe you can reference only one of the items of the array, say `$model->mitra_mous[0]->mitra->nama`.

I am not sure if this solves your issue, but at least that line should work.

Be careful with this solution anyway, because if `$model->mitra_mous` has no elements, the code will fail. Yo may have to add a condition for that case.

Hope I have helped.

Good luck!

Comment: hi @Juan, thanks for the reply.
I've tried $model->mitra_mous[0]->mitra->nama
It produces another error message 
Property "MitraMou.nama" undefined.

Comment: Could you please post the `MitraMou` class relations and attributes? It is hard to find the error without this information.